# Mac OS 10.12 - Accidentally Unlinked libz.1.dylib

Tags: libraries, dynamic-linking, system-recovery

Ran:

`unlink /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib`

Now I can't launch from my user profile.

I have been able to run in recovery mode, where I can see the .dylib in question is there, but running in single-user mode I get the error:

`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib`

`Reason: image not found`

And, if I cd into lib, and type 'ls' libz.1.dylib isn't listed there.

Help please! (I'm out of my depth)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The recovery partition is completely separate from the main OS partition. I'm running 10.15 not 10.12, but the approach will be similar if not identical:

```
hdiutil attach /Volumes/Recovery/*/BaseSystem.dmg
cp '/Volumes/macOS Base System/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib' /usr/lib/
diskutil unmount '/Volumes/macOS Base System'
```

The first line mounts the recovery partition so you can access it. It'll tell you what it mounted as, for me it was `/Volumes/macOS Base System`. Then you can copy the file from there to the main OS partition. The third line then unmounts the recovery image